# How to open image in a modal window from html form file type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I choose an image from a form file input, how can I open the image in a modal popup window?

```
<input type="file" class="form-control">
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please show your code first so that we could understand what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Base64 from the input field and then append it to an `<img>` element, inside your modal. Find details in the link below.

[FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use fancybox, but if you use base64 encode you have to set some setting for the image...like this:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.fancybox-cs').fancybox({
         type        : 'image'
      });
  });
  </script>
```